# SSL certification on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, firefox, openssl

I have a Java web application running on a Debian virtual machine on GCE. 
I'm not sure whether this is relevant (i dont think it is, just in case) - i'm using Vaadin 8 in this system, and thus any HTTP calls to it are handled by a Vaadin servlet.

For SSL certification, i ran the `openssl` commands in [self-signed SSL certificate on GCE -- 'SSL certificate could not be parsed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918836/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-gce-ssl-certificate-could-not-be-parsed) to get CA authorization and generate SSL certification myself. So by this, I'm certifying my SSL by first being a certified authority.

After the commands in [self-signed SSL certificate on GCE -- 'SSL certificate could not be parsed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918836/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-gce-ssl-certificate-could-not-be-parsed), i followed the instructions at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html and did the following:

ran the following two commands without error:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keyalg RSA
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mySite.com.pem -inkey mySite.com.key -out mycert.p12 -name myalias -CAfile msite.CA.pem -caname root -chain
```

The second command generated `mycert.p12` in the directory.

I then configured `server.xml`. Following are all the `configuration` tags there are now in `server.xml`.

```
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="myPasswd"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" /> 
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
…
</Service>
```

Replaced this with the `server.xml` in `conf` directory of Tomcat. Restarted Tomcat. Called my application in Firefox - still seeing the SSL warning:

[image]

As far as i can see, this didn't work because

1. I'm missing something on the configuration of the certificate on Tomcat -- not sure i did things right on `server.xml`. i didnt do anything elsewhere on Tomcat.
2. I did all the configuration right, but Firefox isn't accepting SSL signed by a not-known authority.

I'm not sure (2) can be. the blogs i read tell that generating the `.pem` file connects it to publicized CA-s and should be OK(?)

Any help would be appreciated. this been eating my time for days - i dont know much about SSL or any security matters -- dont even know where to go from here!

Note: seen [Installing SSL certificate on JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394478/installing-ssl-certificate-on-jboss) among some other useful discussions.

//----------------

EDIT:

pls also note; I see no errors on `catalina.out`.

//----------------

EDIT-2:

i'm getting the security warning above (the screenshot image) when I call by `http://`.. in Firefox. the call `https://..` is giving the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you actually change `http://` to `https://` in the URL you're going to in Firefox?

Comment: @JosephSible https giving error - pls see EDIT-2. thx for the useful pointer.

Comment: Did you add the port 8443 to your URL? `https://yourservername:8443/yourApp`