# JBoss6.4 to Jboss7.4 upgrade - SSL certificate configuration issue

Tags: jboss, devops, admin, wildfly-15

I am looking for help to configure SSL related configuration changes in JBoss7.4. I have gone through below solution but it won't work for me

[Installing SSL certificate on JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394478/installing-ssl-certificate-on-jboss)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my question

As per the red hat JBoss7.4 documentation, we need to configure SSL certificate in host.xml, host-master.xml, host-slave.xml files.

if anyone is using JBoss6.4 then we need to configure SSL certificate in domain
XML file under web subsystem.